# how to see the output of created cursor in oracle and how can i call it as function.?

Tags: oracle

How can i see the output of the following code in oracle and call it?

```
DECLARE
       c_id e.id%type;
       c_name e.name%type;
       CURSOR c_e is
          SELECT id, name FROM e;
    BEGIN
       OPEN c_e;
       LOOP
          FETCH c_e into c_id, c_name;
        dbms_output.put_line(c_id||' '||c_name);
         EXIT WHEN c_e%notfound;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE c_e;
   END;
   /
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
create or replace procedure test_out
begin
   DECLARE
       c_id e.id%type;
       c_name e.name%type;
       CURSOR c_e is
          SELECT id, name FROM e;
    BEGIN
       OPEN c_e;
       LOOP
          FETCH c_e into c_id, c_name;
          dbms_output.put_line(c_id||' '||c_name);
          EXIT WHEN c_e%notfound;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE c_e;
   END;
end;
exec test_out;
```